# when line item insert or update a copy of it will insert or update in stock object.(no relationship between them)

Tags: apex

These is a trigger are two unrelated objects  when even a record is inserted or updated it should update the stock also.insert trigger working fine but unable to update the record.

```
trigger stockupdate on Line_Item2__c (before insert,before update) {
List<Stock__c> sto= new List<Stock__c>();

    if(trigger.isinsert){
    for(Line_Item2__c li:trigger.new){
        system.debug(trigger.new);
    sto.add(new Stock__c(Name=li.Product_Code__c,Product_Name__c=li.Product_Name__c,Manufacturing_Date__c=li.Manufacturing_Date__c,Batch_No__c=li.name,Expiry_Date__c=li.Expiry_Date__c,No_Of_Boxes__c=li.No_Of_Boxes__c,Pieces_Per_Box__c=li.Pieces_Per_Box__c,Manufacturer_Name__c=li.Manufacturer_Name__c,Total_No_Of_Pieces__c=li.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c)) ;           

        insert sto;

    }
if(trigger.isupdate){
             for(line_item2__c lt:trigger.new){
 Stock__c st=[select id,name,Product_Name__c,Manufacturing_Date__c,Batch_No__c,Expiry_Date__c,No_Of_Boxes__c,Pieces_Per_Box__c,Manufacturer_Name__c,Total_No_Of_Pieces__c from stock__c where name='lt.Product_Code'];  


                 st.Name=lt.Product_Code__c;
                 st.Product_Name__c=lt.Product_Name__c;
                 st.Manufacturing_Date__c=lt.Manufacturing_Date__c;
                 st.Batch_No__c=lt.name;
                 st.Expiry_Date__c=lt.Expiry_Date__c;
                 st.No_Of_Boxes__c=lt.No_Of_Boxes__c;
                 st.Pieces_Per_Box__c=lt.Pieces_Per_Box__c;
                 st.Manufacturer_Name__c=lt.Manufacturer_Name__c;
                 st.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c=lt.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c;

               sto.add(st);

            }  

            update sto;

             }
    }
}
```

Comment: please reformat the code so it indents properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets aren't balanced properly. As posted, all of your current code is wrapped inside of your `if(trigger.isinsert){`. The next to last closing bracket matches with that one. That's why nothing gets updated since it can't be both insert and update.

Here's how your brackets are supposed to be matched as near as I can tell:

```
trigger stockupdate on Line_Item2__c (before insert,before update) {
List<Stock__c> sto= new List<Stock__c>();

    if(trigger.isinsert){
        for(Line_Item2__c li:trigger.new){
            system.debug(trigger.new);
            sto.add(new Stock__c(Name=li.Product_Code__c,Product_Name__c=li.Product_Name__c,Manufacturing_Date__c=li.Manufacturing_Date__c,Batch_No__c=li.name,Expiry_Date__c=li.Expiry_Date__c,No_Of_Boxes__c=li.No_Of_Boxes__c,Pieces_Per_Box__c=li.Pieces_Per_Box__c,Manufacturer_Name__c=li.Manufacturer_Name__c,Total_No_Of_Pieces__c=li.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c)) ;           
        }
        insert sto;

    }
    sto.clear(); // clear this list in case it's used in the same execution context so it doesn't contain both insert and update records.

    if(trigger.isupdate){
        for(line_item2__c lt:trigger.new){
            Stock__c st=[select id,name,Product_Name__c,Manufacturing_Date__c,Batch_No__c,Expiry_Date__c,No_Of_Boxes__c,Pieces_Per_Box__c,Manufacturer_Name__c,Total_No_Of_Pieces__c from stock__c where name='lt.Product_Code'];  

                 st.Name=lt.Product_Code__c;
                 st.Product_Name__c=lt.Product_Name__c;
                 st.Manufacturing_Date__c=lt.Manufacturing_Date__c;
                 st.Batch_No__c=lt.name;
                 st.Expiry_Date__c=lt.Expiry_Date__c;
                 st.No_Of_Boxes__c=lt.No_Of_Boxes__c;
                 st.Pieces_Per_Box__c=lt.Pieces_Per_Box__c;
                 st.Manufacturer_Name__c=lt.Manufacturer_Name__c;
                 st.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c=lt.Total_No_Of_Pieces__c;

               sto.add(st);
        }  
        update sto;
    }
}
```